# Reading an octave binary file in C++

Tags: c++, octave

I have a binary file, created by Octave containing the values of variables, is there a way to read them into a c++ program so that the values can be used by a c++ class?

Going through an Octave script is acceptable.

The file is created with the command:

```
save("-binary",fileName,myMatrix,"var1","var2");
```

Comment: Have you searched the web for "Octave binary file format": https://www.google.com/search?q=Octave+file+format&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=Octave+binary+file+format&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official

Comment: Is your issue with File I/O or with the file format?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I know how to read the file and get the values in Octave, I want to read and use the values in c/c++. But most importantly, I don't want to write a new parser for binary files, I want to know if it exists already.

Comment: You want a library that can access values in an Octave Binary file.  Have you searched the web for "Octave parser library binary file"?

Answer (score 0):

If you program is licensed under the GPL you can use liboctave/libinterp and link your C++ program against it. See libinterp/corefcn/load-save.cc

http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_wrote_a_program_that_links_with_Octave_libraries_and_I_don.27t_want_to_release_it_under_the_terms_of_the_GPL._Will_you_change_the_license_of_the_Octave_libraries_for_me.3F

See
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html howto write standalone programs which use octave.